# checkbox react-native on api array

Tags: react-native, checkbox

These checkboxes are working returning the values correctly, the problem is that after selecting the first one, I need to click 3 times on the one I want to select to be marked

```
function onChecked(id,valor) {
    const data = adc
    const index = data.findIndex(x => x._id === id)
    data[index].checked = !data[index].checked
    
    setCheck(data[index].checked)

    //alert(valor)
}

<TouchableOpacity key={a._id} onPress={() => {this.onChecked(a._id)}} style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <CheckBox value={a.checked} onValueChange={() => {onChecked(a._id,a.valorA)}}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

the rest works normally only when checking this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

I guess you have a table like this in your state and you are in a React **Component** :

```
adc = [{
    _id: 0,
    checked: false,
    }, {
    _id: 1;
    checked: true,
}];
```

```
onCheck = (id, value) => {
    const index = adc.findIndex(x => x._id === id)  
    adc[index].checked = value;
    this.setState({ adc });
}
```

```
adc.map(i => (
  <CheckBox 
    value={i.checked}
    onValueChange={(v) => onCheck(i._id, v) }
  />
));
```

Comment: it didn't work, I tried to implement adapting to the code but nothing done. what happens in my code, the checkbox takes all the data, the index works, the value, id, any parameter that I send on onpress it returns through the index. when I click on the checkbox it doesn't check

Comment: Ok you don't need any TouchableOpacity following this link: https://reactnative.dev/docs/checkbox I updated answer with more details

Comment: my complete code is here

https://snack.expo.io/@rmbruno/teste

if you want to take a look to help me, it would help a lot

Comment: I try to update your code https://snack.expo.io/@victor.balssa/teste

Comment: in my code the check works, only after selecting the first in the second I have to press 3 times to select or remove the check, since in the updated one it doesn't select but returns the index or parameters normally, the problem is when changing the state checked = false or true